# Range concept for a specific type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

Is there an **already defined *concept*** for specifying a ***range of a specific type***, in C++20 or in the ranges-TS?

Something like:

```
template < class T, class InnerType >
concept RangeOf =
  requires(T&& t) {
    requires std::same_as<
           std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*std::ranges::begin(t))>,
           InnerType
         >;
    std::ranges::end(t);
  };
```

To allow, [for example](https://godbolt.org/z/eWcnzM):

```
void print(const RangeOf<char> auto& char_seq) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: And what happens when you use the concept you've shown?

Comment: @cigien the concept allows to match for a range of a specific inner type, e.g. range of chars, the question is whether such a concept is already proposed or defined.

Comment: Ok, then edit your question to make it clear that the code works, and that you're asking if there is already such a concept in the STL.

Comment: Newbie question: the concept above has 2 template parameters, with ```RangeOf<char>```, how is ```T``` deduced vs. ```InnerType```?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No there isn't.

The way to spell that particular concept would be:

```cpp
template <typename R, typename V>
concept RangeOf = range<R> && same_as<range_value_t<R>, V>;
```

But then it turns out there's a bunch of very closely related things you might want to check as well. You might actually want to look at the `reference` type rather than the `value_type`. Perhaps that's:

```cpp
template <typename R, typename V>
concept RangeOf = range<R> && same_as<range_reference_t<R>, V>;
```

The reason is: do you consider `vector<char>&` to be a range of `char` or a range of `char&`? Arguably, it's more like the latter, and it's the latter that drives a lot more usage. But it's not that the former is wrong; it's useful too, just in a different way.

Then you have to talk about whether you want `same_as` or `convertible_to`. There are some algorithms in which you would want to restrict to the former, and some in which the latter is good enough.

This issue of `same_as` vs `convertible_to`, to me, is one of the motivating reasons for wanting concept template parameters, so that:

```cpp
template <typename R, template <typename> concept C>
concept RangeOf = range<R> && C<range_value_t<R>>;
```

So that I can easily write `RangeOf<same_as<char>>` or `RangeOf<convertible_to<char>>`, depending on what I actually want. However, this brings up other parsing issues too (if `RangeOf` takes a unary concept, how do you make `same_as<char>` - which is not a unary concept but rather a partially applied concept that is not valid in all contexts - work?) so it's unclear how to really make this work. There's currently [a proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2841r1.pdf) for this, but it would not actually handle this use-case especially well (largely because it's not actually clear *how* to handle this use-case especially well).

---

All of which is to say, it's hard to know what actual thing we would want for `RangeOf`, which is why no such thing exists. But each specific thing that would be useful is very easy to write, so the lack of such a thing isn't a especially large burden on the user.

Comment: Leaving it to the user doesn't mean that the user would have in mind all the strong arguments and nuances that you present, thus might be that the user would implement something which misses the subtle differences that you raise. The idea of `RangeOf<same_as<char>>` and `RangeOf<convertible_to<char>>` sounds brilliant to me, was it considered? Or this is also left for the user?

Comment: @AmirKirsh The "strong arguments and nuances" are just... what does the algorithm in question need. Some algorithms need one thing, others need a different thing. The user writing an algorithm should know which constraint the algorithm needs and use the appropriate one. I don't think there's a general answer here.

Comment: @AmirKirsh And we don't have concept template parameters as a language feature, that's why I described it as a motivating reason for wanting such a thing. I don't know what you mean by asking if this was left for the user.

Comment: Got it. It requires _concept template parameters_ which is not supported in C++20 and not planned for C++23. The current alternative could just be for the user to implement `RangeOf<char>` and `RangeOfConvertibleTo<char>` for example.

Comment: IMO most programmers are too lazy and/or don't know the correct syntax to write `requires std::range<R> && std::same_as<std::range_value_t<R>, int>` or whatever on all their functions, they'll probably at best document that the range should be over ints, and leave wrong types to be caught by template substitution failure with verbose error messages and/or allow subtle type conversion bugs. This doesn't seem much better than the old enable_if to me. It would be better to provide all the possible range_of, range_of_ref, range_of_convertible, etc.